# Emails not going from Mandrill to Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mandrill

I'm trying to send email from my app, emails seem to be going to mandrill correctly and there getting delivered, but I see nothing in my inbox.

[image]

I've even tried sending them through my domain and I'm still not getting them. I get them from my live website its using gmail but I want to switch

Using mxtoolbox.com I found

SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch and 
454 4.7.1 Relay access denied  which could mean its been marked for spam?

It's sent through emails twice so I'm wondering if theres a time between emails sent or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandrill blocks certain domains from being the send address to prevent fraud, but as long as you're sending *from* an address you know exists *to* an address you know exists, you should be fine. Also, if that were the problem, the email would bounce rather than send. Also, some email services have policies that prevent you from doing things like sending an email to your address from your address from an external service. Based on that error message you provided, it could be something like that; I would check your provider's policies (and your spam folder).

Comment: It's actually an issue with how I'm receiving mail through Gmail for buis.

Comment: I'm guessing its because I set up Gmail for business, and forwarded it to my regular email and never paid and my account was suspended. I get most emails but some seem to get lost in translation.

Answer (score 12):

When I was testing this I thought my emails where being dropped by gmail. I found that for some reason there was a very long lag going from Mandril to Gmail. I received all my tests about an hour after Mandril sent them. Hope this helps someone stuck like I was.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Also curious if you managed to resolve this. Over a year later I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Found this question trying to diagnose my issue.

I am using Mandrill and found that sending emails from Mandrill to Gmail will take anywhere from 10 seconds to 15 minutes. Can't establish a reason why sometimes it takes longer.

Comment: I finding that emails are not appearing at all. Sometimes they come through to the Gmail account and sometimes they don't. About 40% of the emails sent to Gmail are missing and not appearing in following days.

Comment: I have the same problem. What is weird is that if my application sends an email i can see it in the outbound list as "delivered" instantly. After at most an hour, the email shows up in gmail, but the interesting part is that the delivery says "received xx minutes ago" in Gmail, even though i just got it. It seems gmail is somehow throttling Emails?

Comment: Has anyone heard from Mandrill on this issue?

Comment: All they told me was that it shows as delivered, but is experiencing delays on Gmail's end. It's weird because I send all my emails from the same "from" field.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but if you look on your mandrill Outbound activity page and click on the green icon that says `Delivered` you should see that it says `No smtp events`. 
I don't know why it doesn't send but this show that it hasn't sent. 
Or should I say hasn't arrived where it was supposed to.

Update:

On further investigation I found out that the emails weren't sending because I was using my personal email address as the sender `from_email:` When I changed this to a more business sounding email address it worked. So make something up if you have to, like `no-reply@nonsense.com`